# CSS transition all with position: relative acts jerky on second half of animation

Tags: css

I'm experiencing some inconsistent behavior trying to get an image hover transition to work. Basically, I want it so when the image is hovered over, it zooms in and rotates. To avoid unsightly white space when the image zooms and rotates, I'm trying to move it back a little so it appears to zoom into the middle of the image instead of the top left. Strangely, the first half of the animation (when moused over) works fine, but once the mouse is taken off the image it roughly snaps back to where it was. Transform:rotate continues to animate just fine.

Here's the relevant parts of the offending animation ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xY8EY/2/)):

```
.img-thumbnail {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.img-thumbnail-wrapper img:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -13px;
}
```

This behavior seems to be unique to position: relative. Position: absolute does not properly animate the position in either half of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So immediately after I finished typing out this entire question I figured out what I did wrong: I put `position` inside img:hover. Obviously did not play nicely with transition. Moving `position` to `.img-thumbnail` fixed the issue. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xY8EY/3/))

Whoops.